# Does 'core.sharedrepository' affect working directory?

Tags: git

I cloned a git repository. I would like to ensure that whatever my `umask`, the files in my clone are group writable.

I set `core.sharedrepository` to `group` then `chmod`ded files as needed.

However, when doing a `git checkout whatever`, file permissions are set according to my `umask` and group write is denied.

Is this the expected behavior? Does 'core.sharedrepository' only affect files in `/.git` and not in the working directory?

(I realize that even if it worked as I expected, it wouldn't act on new files created by the user, only on files modified through git actions, so maybe the idea is silly in the first place, but I would like this option clarified for the sake of understanding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, the `core.sharedRepository` setting (or `core.sharedrepository`, case is ignored for these) affects only the repository itself.  It's meant for setups where several users push to a shared repository using their own identities (e.g., by direct access or via ssh-ing as themselves to the server).

Comment: OK, so on a non-bare repo, it affects only the `.git` subdir but not the "working directory". (Just rephrasing to be sure I get it right.)

Comment: Yes (though this also means that on a non-bare repo there's little reason to bother in the first place :-) ).

Comment: Yes, I agree with this. You may imagine someone working on a (non-bare) repo and allowing another user to push in his repo but not checkout. But in practice, it seems tailored for bare repos. The docs left me in doubt. Thanks for clarifying.